# Canvas HTML5 перестроение фигуры по заданным координатам

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

У меня возникла проблема с перестроением фигуры по координатам. На канве нарисованы точки, соединенные линиями.

[image: Фигура]

При клике на канву должно происходить одновременное перемещение точек:

- 1 -> 3
- 2 -> 1
- 3 -> 4
- 4 -> 2

Проблема в том, что координаты не соответствуют заданным.
Например, когда я пытаюсь переместить **точку 1** в **точку 3**, то **точка 1** оказывается в других координатах.

```
particles[0].update(100, 500);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подозреваю, что ошибка в рассчетах движения точек, но не могу обнаружить проблему, так как это работало правильно в другой реализации.

Мой код здесь
https://codepen.io/Stacky/pen/NmMYLo

P.S. Другая реализация с движением точек (но без линий) https://codepen.io/Stacky/pen/bJMMBX

Comment: У Вас же уже есть граф, двигайтесь по его ребрам во время интерполяции

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно, точки должны перемещаться и тянуть за собой линии, не зависеть от них.

Comment: Возможно, будет понятней какая нужна анимация на этом примере (я брал этот код за основу). Только в моем случае координаты должны быть строгими, без рандома. https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/NbNjjX

Comment: Ну точки едут по графу который не меняется, при этом они в каждом кадре соединены, не вижу противоречий

Comment: Если к вечеру у Вас все еще будут сложности с этим, я накидаю пример...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это то, о чем я писал в комментариях, точки едут по ребрам графа, образуемого первоначальным положением точек.

```js
let t, duration = 1000;
let graph = [2, 0, 3, 1];
let coords = [[6, 302], [330, 5], [100, 500], [10, 690]];
let links = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [2,3]]
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let ease = t => t;
window.addEventListener('click', () => animate(t = new Date().getTime()));
draw(0);

function animate() {
    let dt = new Date().getTime() - t;
    draw(Math.min(1, ease(dt/duration)));
    dt <= duration && requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}                          
               
function draw(t) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let pts = graph.map((to,from) => {
        let x1 = coords[from][0];
        let y1 = coords[from][1];
        return [x1 + (coords[to][0] - x1) * t, 
                y1 + (coords[to][1] - y1) * t];
    });
    pts.forEach(pt => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(pt[0], pt[1], 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    })
    links.forEach(link => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(pts[link[0]][0],pts[link[0]][1]);
        ctx.lineTo(pts[link[1]][0],pts[link[1]][1]);
        ctx.stroke();
    })
}
```

```html
<canvas width="350" height="700"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример!

Comment: @Riccu я старался его сделать минимальным для понятности, Вам все понятно?

Comment: Да, более-менее понял.

Comment: @Riccu например я оставил место для Вашей фантазии при реализации функции сглаживания `x =>x`

Comment: @Riccu не стесняйтесь спросить, если что, с радостью отвечу

Comment: не совсем понял как работают связи между точками let links = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [2,3]]. Мы здесь задаем только точки с которыми связывать или можно менять количество связей?

Comment: @Riccu это пары индексов,  описание как соединить иочки в каждом кадре, добавляйте еще суолько угодно

Comment: спасибо, получилось сделать всё что нужно.

Comment: @Riccu ну и прекрасно, обращайтесь